# How can I add the block I'm looking at to my hand in creative?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

This is a feature that I thought existed, maybe I was wrong.  Is there any way to do this?

In a creative world, is there a way to look at a certain block, press a shortcut key, and add the block/item you're looking at into your hand or inventory?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes! By default, that key is set to middle click, so you can change it if your mouse doesn't have that capability.

Answer (score 37):

It is called Pick Block, and by default it is set to <kbd>MMB</kbd> (Middle-click).

In creative, it adds the block to your inventory.

Many people do not know, though, that if you're in survival, you can also use it. When used in survival it puts the block in your hand if you have it in your inventory. For example, if I look at andesite and have andesite in my inventory, I can pick block the andesite and it will move straight to my hand. If you look at a block that is not in your inventory and try to pick block it, nothing happens.

You can also copy the block along with the data. Pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>MMB</kbd> (change <kbd>MMB</kbd> with whatever you bind it to, but <kbd>CTRL</kbd> cannot be changed) will copy the block along with its data. For example, if there is a command block with a command in it just pressing <kbd>MMB</kbd> on it will copy an empty command block. Pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>MMB</kbd> will copy the block along with the command inside of it.

Comment: How does ctrl+mmb work in Survival Minecraft? Does it only select a block in your inventory if it has identical block data (e.g. a command block with the same command block commands programmed into it)? Does it pick the same block, then copy block data over to it?

Comment: @nick012000 in normal non-cheating survival, I do not believe it is possible to get blocks with NBT in them in your inventory. If you just run `/gamemode` and try it I don’t know what would happen. I assume CTRL would do nothing, but that would be something to try out

Comment: @Penguin It's totally possible to get certain blocks with NBT in survival - the most blatant examples are shulkerboxes.

Comment: @SF. oh, I was trying to think of examples and couldn't. Yeah. I still believe CTRL would do nothing though, someone'd still have to try it out